# Add changes to previous commit on git without a rebase

Tags: git

Let's say I have the following commits in my branch:

```
commit A
commit B
commit C
commit D
```

I made some changes that are ready to be committed, however I would like to add these changes to `commit C` since they're more relevant that that commit.

The way I deal with this is by doing a temporary commit `git add . && git commit -m 'temp'`, and then `git rebase -i HEAD~4` in which I will be able to merge `commit temp` and `commit C` together. I was wondering, is there a way to do this without having to create the temporary commit?

Comment: [Automate the process](https://blog.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/). I use the alias all the time.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot modify a commit other than the last one like that.

The reason is that when modifying a commit, all following commits have to be updated as well. They will essentially be recreated since they are now pointing to a new parent. This is what happens during a rebase: A chain of commits is being rewritten.

If you just want to modify the latest commit (HEAD), then there are no commits that have that commit as its parent. So there is no chain of commits that need to be rewritten. In that case, you can just *amend* that commit using `git commit --amend`. This will add whatever staged changes you have to the previous commit. Amending a commit is basically like a rebase for a single commit.

So you cannot really get this done without rebasing. I would personally say that interactive rebasing is the best way to do this: It allows you to just continue committing your changes, and then later, you can reorder or reorganize the commits you have made to improve the history.

What you also *could* do is checkout the commit you want to change, amend it, and then rebase the original branch non-interactively on top of that amended commit. But that gets easily a bit more complicated than interactive rebasing, since now you need to take care of branches and commit references.